# Convert double value to contain decimal seperator and only two digits after comma in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I would like to convert a number such as the following:

```
2937998.7397271004
```

to look like this:

```
2.937.998,73
```

My attempt of achieving this looks as following, but the result still looks the same:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.###.###.###,00");
def val = decimalFormat.format(cell.getNumericCellValue().doubleValue())
return val
```

Comment: Don't you need to supply a *locale* that has `,` as the decimal separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do is to use a locale which supports your formatting pattern. For example `Locale.GERMAN` is in line with what you are expecting

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00",
        DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN));
df.format(2937998.7397271004); // 2.937.998,74
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use Locale for this issue. And in your case formatting is german:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat

NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
println numberFormat.format(2937998.7397271004)
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not familiar with groovy as far as I know it still utilizes the java libraries.

You cannot utilize multipled .'s on a standard DecimalFormat as can be seen in the documentation for the java class: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

So the following line of code needs to changed to:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###.00");
```

Which will respond with 2.937.998,74 utilizing the provided value of 2937998.7397271004.

If you want to do it as 2.937.998,74 you can, again at least in java, do the following.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###.00");
DecimalFormatSymbols custom = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
custom.setDecimalSeparator(',');
custom.setGroupingSeparator('.');
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(custom);

String val = decimalFormat.format(cell.getNumericCellValue().doubleValue());
```

Or use the locale as other aswers sugest.